# Some apps re-enabling themselves in my Redmi phone

Tags: applications, system-apps, miui, redmi

I use Redmi Note11 with MIUI14

For example, I disabled Xiaomi account app and Music app from "Modify system settings" and I disabled Phone permissions from MIUI security components app.
But around 2 days later, those apps re enabled themselves.

Is it a system bug or something I should be worried about?

Thank you.

Comment: Why consider this a "bug" when the simpler reasoning is that it is programmed by the app provider to re-enable itself, overriding your actions? Plenty of precedent around - plenty of precedents reported on this board - search for it.